# Add text between "Retrieved from" and ":" (the colon character) when specifying URL

Tags: apa-style, apa6

According to the 6th edition of the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association, the format (see image below) must be followed if it were necessary to cite a technical or research report that has been retrieved online

[image]

So the question is: **How can I add a text between `Retrieved from` and `:` (the colon character)?**

So far I've found this [document](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/texlive-bibtex-extra/latex/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) ([source code here](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/texlive-bibtex-extra/latex/biblatex-apa/)) which lists some examples from the `biblatex-apa` style, which I suppose is loaded when using `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`. As can be noted in that document, the `7.03:33` example (bottom part of the 8th page) is displayed as:

[image]

Comment: Don't sent lots of snippets and links. Create a small complete example and post it here, that makes testing much easier.

Comment: I really appreciate the advice. Should I create a new question by giving a complete example or edit this question?

Comment: edit the question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found out how to do it. The trick was to use the **`urldescription`** field from the `biblatex-apa` style (which is loaded when using `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`).

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\shorttitle{}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{times}

\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{test1}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`main.bib`

```
@report
{
    test1,
    author = {Kessy, Samantha Samantha Andre and Urio, Frans Martin},
    title = {The contribution of microfinance institutions to poverty reduction in Tanzania},
    year = {2006},
    note = {(Research Report No. 06.3)},
    url = {http://www.repoa.or.tz/documents_storage/Publications/Reports/06.3_Kessey_and_Urio.pdf},
    urldescription = {Poverty Alleviation website}
}
```

Result:

[image]